# Django quickly get latest in one to many relation

Tags: python, django, one-to-many

I have a model in Django like this

```
class Artist(models.model):
    pass

class Track(models.model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I only have a couple hundred `Artist`s that I want to display on a page alongside their latest `Track`. I can fetch all the `Artist`s quickly, but fetching their latest `Track`, when there are thousands of tracks, is proving to be expensive.

```
latest_track = artist.track_set.latest('when') # really expensive
```

The way I add tracks to an artist allows me to easily set an artists latest track (i.e. I don't have to worry about multiple threads). This made me think I should just store a field `Artist#latest_track`, but I don't know how to model that because it's not really a `OneToOneField`, and that's the closest thing I could find.

I also considered using `cached_property`, but I don't have a good way to invalidate the cache at the right time. Also, `cached_property` appears to only setup during runtime, so if I restart my app server, it will need to redo all the queries.

What do I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you just need `prefetch_related` on artists:

```
for artist in Artist.objects.all().prefetch_related('track_set'):
    latest_track = artist.track_set.latest('when') #should be no db hit
```

If it is still slow you need to inspect the generated sql (django debug toolbar, db logs) and see what's going on, often the slowness is coming not from where you expect.

Comment: This is not the correct answer!! artist.track_set.latest('when') HITS DB! In order not to break the prefetch_related you would have to iterate with pure Python, without executing another query.